# Position of volatile keyword in member function declaration in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, volatile

Does the positioning of the 'volatile' keyword in a method declaration affect its functionality?

i.e., is there any difference between the following two pieces of code?

A.

```
class Test
{
public:
    volatile void testMe() 
    {
    }
};
```

B.

```
class Test
{
public:
    void testMe() volatile 
    {
    }
};
```

And same goes when the member function has a return value. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same as for the `const` qualifier.

In the first example, the `volatile` applies to the  return value of the function. It is void in this case, so it doesn't make much sense. In fact, it doesn't make much sense to return by volatile value<sup>*</sup>. A volatile return type would only make sense for a reference:

```
volatile int& foo() { ... }
volatile int& i = foo(); // OK
int j = foo(); // OK, use the volatile reference to construct a non volatile int
int& j = foo(); // Error!
```

In the second case, it means that the method is `volatile`, hence it can be called on (non-const) non-volatile **and** volatile instances of class `Test`. A similar method without the `volatile` qualifier could not be called on a `volatile` instance.

```
Test test0;
test0.testMe(); // OK
volatile Test test1;
test1.testMe(); // OK
test1.someNonVolatileMethod(); // Error.
```

<sup>*</sup>Unless that value is a pointer

Comment: It can also make sense to return a volatile class type by value so that only volatile member functions can be called on the temporary.  I'm not saying I've ever seen this, but it does seem reasonable.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y i have to seriously think about that one. I guess you've identified a case where it differs from `const`, where a `const` return value would mess up move semantics.

Answer (score 3):

The same rules that apply to `const` apply to `volatile`.

When returning `void` (rather not returning), `volatile` is useless in the first snippet.

The second snippet marks the whole method as `volatile`.

For example, if you have:

```
volatile Test m;
m.testMe();
```

only compiles is `testMe` is marked as `volatile` (like your second code).